# Postgres Issue(unable to connect db,role not exists)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.2

I am using postgres.I have create new user postgres to create postgres db and user.But every time i am getting "Role postgres not exists".I have also checked /etc/hosts/ in which my host and machine name is correct.I have tried many command but unable to resolve issue.I am using ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Comment: Start the postgres server first then try

Comment: try postgres from webmin

Comment: ok...I try sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart but it is not working

Comment: @GauravNeema I also tried  sudo service postgresql start
.But getting unrecognized service.

Comment: @Surabhiv Seems like you have messed up something in server. Purge postgreslq and install it again, all databases will be restored.

Comment: @GauravNeema I already purged it and try agian.Can you please suggest any good tutorial.I

Comment: @Surabhiv Follow this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: ok..Thanks.I will try.